# jQuery UI dialog - grab text from table DIV and show - only happens on first click

Tags: jquery-ui, dynamic, html-table, dialog, cell

I'm trying to get some text in a table cell into a jQuery UI dialog dynamically, firing from a link in the table (one for each row). It works for each link once, but thereafter it stops.

Here's my Javascript:

```
$(function() {
        $( ".abstractlink" ).click(function() {
            $( $(this).parent().find('.abstract') ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: true,
            height: "auto",
            width: "600",
            draggable: "true",
            title: "Project abstract",
            resizable: "false"
            });
        });
    });
```

The problem is (I think) that I'm re-initialising the dialog each time a link is clicked. Trouble is, I need to change the DIV which is to be displayed each time a link is clicked (hence finding the element with the class 'abstract' in the parent (TR) element.

Here's the relevant part of the table's code:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" class="abstractlink">View</a><div class="abstract" id="project_abstract_3">Project 3 abstract. Lorem ipsum.</div></td>
</tr>
```

I have a strong feeling that this isn't a very elegant way of solving this problem, but as I'm still new to jQuery I am so I was glad I got this far.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) say:

> A call to $(foo).dialog() will
>   initialize a dialog instance and will
>   auto-open the dialog by default. If
>   you want to reuse a dialog, the
>   easiest way is to disable the
>   "auto-open" option with:
>   $(foo).dialog({ autoOpen: false }) and
>   open it with $(foo).dialog('open'). To
>   close it, use $(foo).dialog('close').

More info [here](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/).

*Edit*: Warning, untested code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".abstract").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: "auto",
        width: "600",
        draggable: "true",
        title: "Project abstract",
        resizable: "false"
    });

    $('.abstractlink').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.abstract').dialog('open');
    });
```

You're not creating one dialog box, you're creating a dialog box for every abstract div. Then, you're telling them to open when needed.

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to dynamically specify the DIV which should be used as the dialog's content. If I initialise the dialog instance, that's only one version of the dialog - I need to be able to do that one the fly.

Comment: I'm still assuming that using multiple dialog boxes will be okay, but so far I don't see a reason why you need a single dialog box and to replace the content on the fly. If that's the case, make one dialog box that isn't actually part of your table, and on click replace the content of the div with the content of the div you want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want something like:

```
$(".abstractlink").live("click", function(){
  // do the onClick work in here
  });
```